# PHP removes session after mysql_connect

Tags: php, session

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
require 'config/database.php';    
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
```

i have problem because i lose session after include databse.php file...

database.php

```
$user = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database = "xxx";
$server = '98.x.x.126';

mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
```

PHP ver: 5.2.17, shared server. on my local server which is 5.3 and 5.4 is working perfectly.

Update: i don't lose the session totally just the user value is changed to database name?

Update2:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
$user = "denes_lucky";
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
$password = "123456X3M";
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
$database = "denes_lucky";
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
$server = '98.130.0.126';
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);

mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
mysql_select_db($database);
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
```

the problem is after $user = "xxx";

Comment: What if you perform `var_dump` after every line in `database.php`? That way you would stop guessing and believing to some mambo-jumbo and know for sure what exactly causes the issue.

Comment: I try to get the bool of the database select db function and it is true, so im able to select db from mysql server

Comment: Great, and what about my proposal?

Comment: replace mysql_connect($server, $user, $password); by mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error()); and mysql_select_db($database); by mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error()); for starters. You're probably never reaching the second var_dump

Comment: i try your suggestion and i get the changed result after user = "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off `register_globals` in your `php.ini` or in `.htaccess`

When they are turned on - assigning `$user = 'foo';` also modified the contents of `$_SESSION['user']` variable.

Comment: im not able to change the ini file due to shared server, can i do this with ini_set()?

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov As ridiculous as it is in this day and age, I suspect this is the right answer. If you are unable to turn this off, rename your `$user` variable to something else. I would *highly* recommend you contact the server administrator and ask them to disable it though.

Comment: @Emrah Mehmedov: nope, you cannot do it with `ini_set()`. When your code is run - it's already too late to turn off register_globals. (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) What if you put `php_flag register_globals 0` to your `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are running an outdated version of PHP and have the `register_Globals`  setting turned on. `register_globals`  was a feature in PHP which made session and request variables global variables. This means that $_SESSION['user'] and $user refer to the same variable.

The best solution is to turn of `register_globals` in your php.ini (or even update to a recent PHP version not having the feature)

A workaround is to rename one of those variables.

See also: http://php.net/register_globals and http://php.net/security.globals